# Mattooltip doesn't work in *ngFor Angular 13

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, tooltip

Mat tool tip doesn't work. Angular 13
I need mat tool tip to show expected value under following condition but it disables checkbox and doesn't show any tooltips

```
<div class="row checkboxes availability">
      <mat-checkbox
        *ngFor="let sampleAvailability of sampleAvailabilityOptions; let i = index"
        [formControlName]="sampleAvailability.id"
        [color]="'primary'"
        id="sample-availability-status-checkbox"
        [id]="'sample-availability-status-checkbox-' + i"
        #tooltip="matTooltip"
        [matTooltip]="
          sampleAvailability.name === 'Checked-in'
            ? 'This sample is available'
            : 'This sample is checked out'
        "
      >
        {{ sampleAvailability.name }}
      </mat-checkbox>
    </div>
```

I tried to write condition according the documentation. If i remove tooltips then checkboxes work fine

Comment: it worked for me, I used angular 15 though , https://angular-ivy-rebjb4.stackblitz.io . share the package json and corresponding ts and html file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabled elements don't show tooltips.

Wrap any disableable elements and put the tooltip on that instead.

E.g.

```html
<span [matTooltip]="
          sampleAvailability.name === 'Checked-in'
            ? 'This sample is available'
            : 'This sample is checked out'">
    <mat-checkbox ...>
        {{ sampleAvailability.name }}
    </mat-checkbox>
</span>
```